# One to One relationship in factory - Integrity Error

Tags: python, django, testing, factory, factory-boy

I'm using factory_boy to create the factories of the app I'm working on.
I'm having an issue when trying to create the **factory of a model which has a one to one relationship to another model**.

Here are the models:

```
class Playlist(AccountDependantMixin, models.Model):
    test = models.OneToOneField('core.PlaylistTest', related_name='playlist')

class PlaylistTest(Test):
    pass
```

AccountDependantMixin is a class which contains extra information. It's outside because others models need it too.
I have different kinds of test. That's why PlaylistTest is empty

This are the factories:

```
class PlaylistTestFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = PlaylistTest


class PlaylistFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Playlist       
    test = factory.SubFactory(PlaylistTestFactory)
```

And here is how I'm trying to initialize the instance with the factory:

```
self.playlist = PlaylistFactory(creator=AdminUserFactory(account=self.account))
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "test_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, , playlist0, sub_title0, description0, 0, t, f, 2016-03-31 12:49:23.739207+00, 0, 2, 1, null)
```

Comment: What is AccountDependantMixin?

Comment: @daniel It's a class which contains extra information. It's outside because others models need it too.

Comment: You don't have any attributes in `PlaylistTestFactory` maybe this is why related object is not  being created and is set to null instead?

Comment: @v1k45 I added a field to PlaylistTest then setted it in the factory, but it didn't solve it

Comment: What is the name of the primary key column in PlaylistTest? Can you add that to your snippet?

Comment: @Oin I got the following name:
In [4]: PlaylistTest._meta.pk.name
Out[4]: u'test_ptr'

Should it be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had another model with another one to one to another class that inherited from Test.

I added the subfactory to the factory of this other class and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

`test = factory.RelatedFactory(PlaylistTestFactory)`

You need to use a `SubFactory` rather than a `RelatedFactory` so that it creates the test object first:

> A RelatedFactory behaves mostly like a SubFactory, with the main
>   difference that the related Factory will be generated **after** the
>   base Factory.

https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#factory.RelatedFactory